# Python:Expected an indented block

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run 2 python programs with mapreduce and keep getting an error whenever I run them. Below is the code for the 2 files. It keeps telling me that there expected an indented block error appears at the main(sys.argv) command in both programs. Any guidance would be apprecaited.

Mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Be sure the indentation is identical and also be sure the line above this is on the first line

import sys
import re

def main(argv):
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    pattern = re.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
    while line:
        for word in pattern.findall(line):
            print(word+"\t"+"1")
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
#Note there are two underscores around name and main
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv)
```

reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Be sure the indentation is correct and also be sure the line above this is on the first line

import sys

def main(argv):
    current_word = None
    current_count = 0
    word = None
    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()
        word, count = line.split('\t', 1)
        count = int(count)
        if current_word == word:
            current_count += count
        else:
            if current_word:
                print('%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count))
            current_count = count
            current_word = word
    if current_word == word:
        print('%s\t%s' % (current_word, current_count))

#Note there are two underscores around name and main
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv)
```

Error Message:

```
[maria_dev@sandbox-hdp ~]$ python reducer.py                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "reducer.py", line 25
    main(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       ^                                                                                                                                                                                                           
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Example of Mapper file [image: Mapper.py]

Comment: Remove the spaces before `if __name__ == "__main__":` That's what giving you indent error I think. Currently you have indented them to be a part of the `main` function itself.

Comment: Ill give that a shot. Ive tried it inside the main() function and outside it and it appears to act the same

Comment: Please include the complete error message. It tells you _where_ is your problem.

Comment: see above. I edited the post to include the error message

Comment: When I just copy paste your both functions as such in JuPyter notebook, I get no error

Comment: my bad. I have updated the error message

Comment: Do you have any whitespaces on the line before the comment `#Note t...`?

Comment: Are you sure that you `main(sys.argv)` is **within** the `if __name__ == "__main__":` and not at the same indent level?

Comment: I added the picture of what the code is supposed to look like. So it appears that main(sys.argv) is supposed to be inside the if __name__ code

Answer (score 2):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # some
    # commands
    # doing
    # stuff
```

This is a nice little "trick" in Python that's used when writing libraries. When you `import` a library you usually just want to import the classes and functions but don't want to execute examplary code. This is different when you execute a library file as a standalone script. When you do this, you'd expect the output of some examples on how to use that library. In Python this is achieved with `if __name__ == "__main__":`. `__name__` is a variable containing a string that's specific for the current file. For the main file this string always the the value `"__main__"` so it's an easy way to tell whether a file is the main file executed or just some library.

The main problem is the indentation. Python can only tell logical code blocks (eg. function definitions, bodies of if-clauses or loops) by indentation. If Python tells you there's an `IndentationError`, then malformatted code is very likely the cause. This error can also be raised if you mix tabs and spaces, so be careful to avoid that. The gold standard is indenting with 4 spaces, never tabs.

Also, using `if __name__ == "__main__":` almost never makes sense in an indented context. It's fairly save to either remove that block entirely (if you only ever use these files as libraries) or to unindent it, so that the `if` is fully unindented and the body of the if-clause is indented with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block outside the `main` function.